# Applying a texture to a cube shows up in the editor under the texture viewport and doesn't in render

Tags: texturing, uv

I have applied a texture to a cube in Blender 2.69 (unable to upgrade at this time) following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il7ajiCepus. It shows up in texture view, as well as solid, but it will not show up in render. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. I followed the tutorial I linked to exactly, I think.

Comment: yeah, whenever there is something you don't think would be reasonable for us to say "Oh yeah! Here's is your problem and here's how you fix it!" or there is something that could be caused by several factors, it's helpful to upload a .blend file. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33280 is the .blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i had a look , but no textures were in the file so i took a guess , What i THINK is wrong is that you have assigned the material with no texture , To fix this , in the image below there are 2 materials , click the negative button ( make sure you have selected the material with no texture ) . Then go into edit mode , and press a until everything is selected , Click the logo material and click assign

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: :D Yay , No problem bro !